# Prove $\cos x \leqslant 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$

Tags: calculus

Help me with this problem:

> $\cos x \leqslant 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$ for every $x \in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}) $

The answer uses maclaurin series but I thought you can only use maclaurin series when $x$ close to $0$?

Comment: Do you what is Taylor's theorem?

Comment: The Maclaurin series for $\cos x$ converges for all real numbers $x$

Comment: @pmac I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Can you prove $\sin x\ge x-\frac{x^3}6$ for $x\ge0$?

Comment: @pmac : Are you sure about the question ?  for example putt $$x=.01 \\cos (0.01)=.999999985\\1 - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}=0.99995$$ ?!! I think ,somthing is missing

Comment: @Khosrotash, the value of $\cos(0.01)$ you are quoting is actually value of $\cos (0.01^o)$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$$
$$x\mapsto 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cos x$$
$$\implies f(0)=0$$
$$\implies f'(x)=\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}, f'(0)=0$$
$$\implies f''(x)=\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}{2}, f''(0)=0$$
$$\implies f'''(x)=-\sin x+x, f'''(0)=0, f'''(x)>0\forall x>0$$
Hence, $f''$ is increasing after $0$, so it is positive for positive $x$. So, $f'$ is increasing after $0$, so it is positive for positive $x$. Therefore, $f$ is increasing after $0$, so it is positive for positive $x$, which is what you want to prove.

Comment: Thank you this way to solve the problem is so cool ! I would never think of this

Comment: @pmac, Thank You comments are deprecated by stackexchange (though we appreciate the sentiment). You can upvote this answer to show your approval and click on the check mark to accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality can be iteratively generated as below,

$$f_1(x) =x-\sin x=\int_0^x (1-\cos t)dt \ge 0$$

$$f_2(x) =\frac{ x^2}2-1 +\cos x 
=\int_0^x f_1(t)dt \ge 0$$

$$f_3(x) =\frac{x^3}6-x +\sin x 
=\int_0^x f_2(t)dt \ge 0$$

$$\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2 }2+1-\cos x 
=\int_0^x f_3(t)dt \ge 0$$

Thus,

$$\cos x \leqslant 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$$

Answer (score 2):

Famously such $x$ satisfy $0<\sin x<x$, and we can use this to bound $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ with polynomials. From$$1-\frac{x^2}{2}<1-\int_0^x\sin tdt=\cos x<1$$we get$$x-\frac{x^3}{6}<\sin x=\int_0^x\cos tdt<x$$and$$1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}<1-\int_0^x\sin tdt=\cos x<1-\frac{x^2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in (0,\frac\pi2)$. Then $\sin x < x.$ Let $f(x) = x-\sin x$ and $g(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{2} + \cos x$. Then $f(x) > 0$ on $(0,x)$. By the Mean Value Theorem (MVT), $f(x_1) = g'(x_1) = \dfrac{g(x)- g(0)}{x}$ for some $x_1 \in (0, x)$. Hence $\dfrac{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + \cos x - 1}{x} > 0$ on $(0,x)$.

Let $h(x) = \dfrac{x^3}{6} + \sin x - x$. Then by MVT again, $g(x_2) = h'(x_2) = \dfrac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}$ for some $x_2\in (0,x)$. Hence $\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\sin x - x > 0$ on $(0,x)$.

Now let $k(x) = \dfrac{x^4}{24}-\cos x -\dfrac{x^2}{2}$. By the MVT, $\exists x_3\in (0,x)$ such that $$h(x_3) = k'(x_3) = \dfrac{k(x)-k(0)}{x} > 0\Rightarrow \dfrac{\dfrac{x^4}{24}-\cos x - \dfrac{x^2}{2}+1}{x}>0\\
\Rightarrow\cos x \leq 1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{24}$$ on $(0,\frac\pi2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you can solve this problem but are simply concerned about convergence.

You are quite right to associate a Maclaurin series with a range of values for which the series is valid. However this range is not necessarily small. In the case of cos, the series converges for **all** real $x$.

In thinking about this idea of a sequence converging for a range of values, you might find it helpful to consider the sum of an infinite GP. As you will know, in this case we have convergence if the common ratio satisfies $-1<r<1$. Again, $r$ does not have to be small - it just has to be smaller in modulus than $1$.

Comment: As I see it, this problem isn't at all about the full Maclaurin series. Just the first three terms.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof without any Taylor formula. Let $f(x) = x^4/24 - x^2/2 + 1 - \cos(x)$, then its 4-th derivative is $f^{(4)}(x) = 1-\cos(x) \ge 0$. Hence $f^{(3)} = x/24 - \sin(x)$ increases but $f^{(3)}(0) = 0$, hence $f^{(2)}$ has a global minimum at $x= 0$. But $f^{(2)}(0) = 1/2\ge 0$, hence $f'$ increases, but again $f'(0) = 0$, hence $f$ has a global minimum at $x=0$. Conclusion: $f(x)\ge f(0) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that\begin{align}\cos x&=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}-\cdots\\&=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}\overbrace{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{7\times8}\right)}^{\phantom{0}>0}-\frac{x^{10}}{10!}\overbrace{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{9\times10}\right)}^{\phantom{0}>0}-\cdots\\&<1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!},\end{align}since $x^2<\frac{\pi^2}4<7\times8<9\times10<\cdots$.