# How to prove that the following series is $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{x}{j}-\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)$ convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{x}{j}-\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{j}\right)\right)<\infty$$ I know that it has to be done by comparing it to $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{j^2}$, because my teacher has indicated me towards that way, but can't really see it

Comment: Is $x$ an arbitrary real number? It should be $> -1$ so that the $ \ln$ is well defined.

Answer (score 2):

The function

$$y-\log(1+y)$$ has a smooth minimum at $y=0$, hence it must be upper-bounded by some parabola in the neighborhood of $0$.

For example, it is easy to see that

$$0<\dfrac{y-\log(1+y)}{y^2}<1$$ in $[-\frac14,\frac14]$.

Hence as of $j\ge4|x|$,

$$0\le\frac xj-\log\left(1+\frac xj\right)\le\frac1{j^2}.$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Let $f(x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln(1+x)$. Check it's sign at $0$ and differentiate it to find its increasing decreasing nature. What do you get?

Comment: In what way does this help ?

Comment: It gives the full solution. This function takes value $0$ at $0$ and is decreasing further. This means that given series is bounded by $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1{j^2}$, which is convergent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I think you should also have given just a hint, because the OP hasn't shown much progress except what his teacher has told him.

Comment: @Downvoter, please comment and tell me what do you disapprove.

Comment: Makes sense now. How did you guess $f$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Using the taylor series is often helpful in such problems. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3490941/609343) for example.

Comment: I see. You need to be lucky that the remainder has the right sign then. Thanks.